# numpy generates error message in python 3.8.3

Tags: python, macos, numpy

I have been running Anaconda python for several years on my iMac. I'm using it mostly for numerical calculation so I use numpy in most of my scripts. Recently it seems to have quit working. I updated Anaconda and ran `conda install numpy`.  However when I try to run simple codes using numpy I get error messages and the code ends. To get to the basics, I ran my Hello_World.py program and it ran fine.

```
print ("Hello World")
x = 0
print(np.cos(x))
```

Next I added 1 line and changed print(x) to print(cos(x)) so that code reads:

```
 import numpy as np
 print ("Hello World")
 x = 0
 print(np.cos(x))
```

These are the only changes but now I get the following error messages:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "hello_World.py", line 1, in 
import numpy as py
File "/Users/johnhanly/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/**init**.py", line 152, in 
from . import random
File "/Users/johnhanly/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/random/**init**.py", line 181, in 
from . import _pickle
File "/Users/johnhanly/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/random/_pickle.py", line 1, in 
from .mtrand import RandomState
File "mtrand.pyx", line 1, in init numpy.random.mtrand
File "_bit_generator.pyx", line 40, in init numpy.random._bit_generator
File "/Users/johnhanly/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/secrets.py", line 20, in 
from random import SystemRandom
File "/Users/johnhanly/random.py", line 2, in 
x = random.randint(100)
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'numpy.random' has no attribute 'randint' (most likely due to a circular import)

I am running the codes from the terminal by typing

```
python hello_world.py
```

Why does numpy cause my programs to crash.

BTW, the code with numpy runs using Spyder but crashes using the command line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a file called `random.py` in location `"/Users/johnhanly/random.py"`
python is trying to import that one rather than numpy so please delete or rename the file.

Comment: That fixed it!  Thank you very much.  Why would that file cause a problem?  Thanks again.

Comment: because when you do  `import random` it looks for random.py in current directory and path. and your `random.py` doesn't have the method  `random.randint` so it  fails to import

Comment: ok thanks. i guess using random in a file name was bad idea.  Thanks again.